# Work With a Value in a Data Frame by Character

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a column of text formatted by NBA season as such:

```
Year
2014-15
2013-14
2012-13
...
1999-00
```

I need to reformat this by the second year. This is a small data set, and I don't mind manually fixing the 1999-00 value, but I can't figure out how to:

```
paste(data$Year[1:2],data$Year[6:7])
```

To get:

```
Year
2015
2014
2013
...
2000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be simplest to just extract the first year and add one:

```
as.numeric(substr(data$Year, 1, 4)) + 1
# [1] 2003 2002 2001 2000 1999
```

Data:

```
(data <- data.frame(Year=c("2002-03", "2001-02", "2000-01", "1999-00", "1998-99")))
#      Year
# 1 2002-03
# 2 2001-02
# 3 2000-01
# 4 1999-00
# 5 1998-99
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you so much. Why does the substr function work on every row, but paste function doesn't let me?

Comment: @StatDance you can't index individual characters of a string with something like `data$Year[1:2]`. Your code would instead need to be something like `paste0(substr(data$Year, 1, 2), substr(data$Year, 6, 7))`, but this still suffers from the "1900" problem.